# Finding containing MethodDeclarationSyntax for a given SyntaxNode

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I have the following source code:

```
public void MethodAssignment_WithIndexQuery_1(Customer from1, Customer to1, decimal amount) 
{
     var customers = _customerRepository.GetWhere(to1.Age);
     Customer indexCustomer1 = customers[(from1.Age + to1.Age)* to1.Age];
}
```

and I have as a given the SyntaxNode: node = **from1.Age** of the expression in the index argument.

Doing this yields null:

```
MethodDeclarationSyntax callingMethod = node
                .GetLocation()
                .SourceTree
                .GetRoot()
                .FindToken(location.SourceSpan.Start)
                .Parent
                .AncestorsAndSelf()
                .OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>()
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

Doing `node.Parent.Parent` returns `BinaryExpressionSyntax AddExpression from1.Age * to2.Age+ to1.Age * to2.Age` and doing *Parent* of that yields **null**.

How can I find the `MethodDeclaration` that encloses the given syntax node?

Comment: Use a SyntaxWalker

Comment: How exactly to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `SyntaxWalker` allows you to find specific nodes. Here is an example how you fetch all the `AddExpression` nodes:

```
public class MethodDeclarationSyntaxWalker : CSharpSyntaxWalker
{
    private readonly IList<MethodDeclarationSyntax> _matches;

    public MethodDeclarationSyntaxWalker( IList<MethodDeclarationSyntax> matches )
    {
        _matches = matches;
    }

    public override void VisitBinaryExpression( BinaryExpressionSyntax node )
    {
        if ( node.Kind() == SyntaxKind.AddExpression )
            _matches.Add( node.FirstAncestorOrSelf<MethodDeclarationSyntax>() );

        base.VisitBinaryExpression( node );
    }
}
```

If you pass this in the `Accept` function of a declarationsyntax and it will collect the matches the given node. For example:

```
var classDeclaration = ( ClassDeclarationSyntax )analysisContext.Node;
var matches = new List<MethodDeclarationSyntax>();
classDeclaration.Accept( new MethodDeclarationSyntaxWalker( matches ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the node's enclosing method via `Ancestors()`:

```
MethodDeclarationSyntax callingMethod = node
                .Ancestors()
                .OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>()
                .FirstOrDefault();
```